# How can I permanently set the options of jquery.typer()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Layervault's jquery.typer (https://github.com/layervault/jquery.typer.js), with a timeout function to delay it.

I'm trying to use their default formula on the page for setting the options permanently, but, if I either write:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('[data-typer-targets]').typer();
}, 4500);
$.typer.options.typerInterval = 3500;
```

or

```
$.typer.options.typerInterval = 3500;
setTimeout(function(){
    $('[data-typer-targets]').typer();
}, 4500);
```

The typer initializes, but the options don't remain in place; the typerInterval always reverts back to the default of 2000. If I hard code the change in jquery.typer.js source, the change is permanent. I'm thinking it might be a lack of understanding javascript sytax? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$('[data-typer-targets]').typer({
    typerInterval : 3500
});
```

do like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.typer.options.typerInterval = 3500;
    $('[data-typer-targets]').typer();
}, 4500);
```

Comment: The typer() function doesn't take arguments, but this would seem to be a better way for it to have been written!

Comment: @YPCrumble check my added answer